# Field Level Access in MongoDB 2.6 using $redact Operator

Tags: json, mongodb, security

I have a document Structure with nested subsections, and i only want to retrieve subsection that matches the Tag that is passed in. Below is the json structure.

```js
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "title" : "Document Formatting",
        "creationDate" : 2014,
        "tags" : [ 
            "GLTW", 
            "SP", 
            "TK"
        ],
        "subsections" : [ 
            {
                "subtitle" : "Section 1: Overview",
                "tags" : [ 
                    "SI", 
                    "GLTW"
                ],
                "content" : "Section 1: This is the content of section 1.",
                "subsections" : [ 
                    {
                        "subtitle" : "Section 1.1: Analysis",
                        "tags" : [ 
                            "SP"
                        ],
                        "content" : "Section 1.1: This is the content of section 1.1.",
                        "subsections" : [ 
                            {
                                "subtitle" : "Section 1.1.1: Analysis",
                                "tags" : [ 
                                    "TK"
                                ],
                                "content" : "Section 1.1.1: This is the content of section 1.1.1."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] }
```

Below is the query i tried and it is not working:

```js
var userAccess = ["TK"]; 
db.redact.aggregate(    [
        { $match: { creationDate: 2014 } },
        { $redact:
            {
               $cond:
                  {
                    if: { $gt: [ { $size: { $setIntersection: [  "$tags",userAccess ] } }, 0 ] },
                    then: "$$DESCEND",
                    else: "$$PRUNE"
                  }
            }
        }    ] )
```

Above query returns nothing.

However if I change the userAccess to `var userAccess = ["TK","SP","GLTW"];`, it is working fine. How can i get only the subsection which matched the userAccess in this case just userAccess=["TK"]. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: someone with "TK" can't see document tagged with "SI",  "GLTW" so it's being pruned (correctly)

Comment: Only way to see subsection tagged with "TK" is to set userAccess something like this. var userAccess = ["SI","SP","TK"]; but i do not want to see SI, and SP , just the subsections tagged with "TK" , i guess this is not the right way to approach.

Comment: right - since TK is inside SP section which is inside SI section, it's logical that you need permissions to see all three. I.e. if you don't have permission for a document, there is no way to even "know" that you can see its subdocument.

Comment: One more question, can i add additional filter on top of $redact to just get subsection 1, assuming there are multiple subsections  ? something like $slice on top of $redact ?